# Will the cublas kernel functions automatically be synchronized with the host?

Tags: cublas

Just a general question about cublas. For a single thread, if there is not memory transfer from GPU to CPU (e.g. cublasGetVector), will the cublas kernel functions (eg cublasDgemm) automatically be synchronized with the host?

```
    cublasDgemm();
//cublasGetVector();
    host_functions()
```

Furthermore, what about between two adjacent kernel calls?

```
cublasDgemm();
cublasDgemm();
```

and, what about a synchronized transfer that does not involve the global memory used in the previous kernel?

```
cublasDgemm(...gA...gB...gC);
cublasGetVector(...gD...D...);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the CUBLAS API is, with the exception of a few Level 1 routines which return a scalar value, asynchronous.

Level 3 routines like `cublasDgemm` don't block the host, you need to call a blocking API routine like a synchronous memory transfer or an explicit host-GPU synchronisation call to ensure that the CUBLAS call has completed.

Comment: Thanks! Now what about between two kernels, and what about a synchronous memory transfer does not involve the global memory used in the previous kernel? (the above post updated as well).

Comment: Kernels are always launched asynchronously and synchronous memory transfers are (except in one case) always synchronous. So you dgemm calls won't block and your memory transfers will block.